# MeteorJS: List in HTML is wigging out

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have this code:

```
Meteor.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('jobs', Session.get('currentIndustryOnet'));
  Meteor.subscribe('cities');
});

Template.selector.events({
  'click div.select-block ul.dropdown-menu li': function(e) {
    var selectedIndex = $(e.currentTarget).attr("rel");
    var val = $('select#industryPicker option:eq(' + selectedIndex + ')').attr('value');
    var oldVal = Session.get('currentIndustryOnet');

    if(val != oldVal) {
      Session.set('jobsLoaded', false);
      Session.set('currentIndustryOnet', val);

      Meteor.call('countByOnet', val, function(error, results){
        if(results > 0) {
          Session.set('jobsLoaded', true);
          plotCities(val);
        } else {
          getJobsByIndustry(val);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

var getJobsByIndustry = function(onet) {
  if(typeof(onet) === "undefined")
      alert("Must include an Onet code");

  var params = "onet=" + onet + "&cn=100&rs=1&re=500";
  return getJobs(params, onet);
}

var getJobs = function(params, onet) {
  Meteor.call('retrieveJobs', params, function(error, results){
    $('job', results.content).each(function(){
      var jvid = $(this).find('jvid').text();
      var job = Jobs.findOne({jvid: jvid});
      if(!job) {
        options = {}
        options.title = $(this).find('title').text();
        options.company = $(this).find('company').text();
        options.address = $(this).find('location').text();
        options.jvid = jvid;
        options.onet = onet;
        options.url = $(this).find('url').text();
        options.dateacquired = $(this).find('dateacquired').text();
        var id = createJob(options);
      }
    });
    plotCities(onet);
    Session.set('jobsLoaded', true);
  });
}

var plotCities = function() {
  Deps.autorun(function(){
    jobs = Jobs.find({onet: Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')}).fetch();
    var addresses = _.chain(jobs)
                .countBy('address')
                .pairs()
                .sortBy(function(j) {return -j[1];})
                .map(function(j) {return j[0];})
                .first(100)
                .value();

    gmaps.clearMap();
    $.each(_.uniq(addresses), function(k, v){
      var addr = v.split(', ');

      Meteor.call('getCity', addr[0].toUpperCase(), addr[1], function(error, city){
        if(city) {
          var opts = {};
          opts.lng = city.loc[1];
          opts.lat = city.loc[0];
          opts.population = city.pop;
          gmaps.addMarker(opts);
        }
      });
    })
  })
}

Template.list.jobs = function() {
  var jobs;

  if(Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')) {
    jobs = Jobs.find({onet: Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')}).fetch();
    return Pagination.collection(jobs);
  } else {
    jobs = Jobs.find()
    Session.set('jobCount', jobs.count());
    return Pagination.collection(jobs.fetch());
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template name="list">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {{#if jobsLoaded}}
      <ul class="list-group" id="jobs">
        {{#each jobs}}
          <li>
            <span class="pull-right">{{address}}</span>
            <span id="jobTitle">{{{ jobUrl url title }}}</span>
            <span id="company">{{company}}</span>
            <span id="date"><em>{{dateacquired}}</em></span>
          </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{else}}
      {{> spinner}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>

  {{#if jobsLoaded}}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            {{#if jobs}}
              <select id="perPage" class="selectpicker select-block" _val="{{selected_opt}}">
                <option value="10">10 Per Page</option>
                <option value="25">25 Per Page</option>
                <option value="50">50 Per Page</option>
                <option value="100">100 Per Page</option>
              </select>
            {{/if}}
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-10">
            {{{pagination}}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

So, when you select an industry from a drop down list. The code checks to see if there are any `Jobs` with the selected onet code. If there are jobs, then the HTML is updated, if not, an API call is made to a XML service to retrieve more.

Here is what happens when the API call is made and the HTML is updated: http://screencast.com/t/SyiawXvDXNmc

Comment: I'm suspecting some async result and autorun problem here. Try to convert your server side methods to sync style. Instead of using a callback, use it like result = meteor.call(...) and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: It's currently just an intuition. Haven't had time to go through the complete code.